# Launching application within another application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to launch an application that already exist in device on the click of home button in iphone when some other application is running .

I have implemented launching an app from a running app but i wanted to launch it when the running application goes into background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you could call the method to launch the other application, I'm pretty sure this violates Apple's policy on use of the home button. If you plan to submit your app, you will almost certainly get rejected for this practice.

For details, see [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1).

Answer (score 2):

You can detect when the application goes into the background by implementing the `UIApplicationDelegate` method: `applicationDidEnterBackground:`.  [Here's a UIApplicationDelegate protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is against the Apple's Human Interface Guidelines . Even if you do it the app will not be approved

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is possible, but have you tried launching the other app with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:...]` and placing that in your AppDelegate's applicationWillResignActive or applicationDidEnterBackground methods?

If that doesn't work, you may succeed with requesting more time to complete background tasks, kicking off a new thread, and calling it from the thread, although I also doubt this will work.

If any of these do work, I fully expect Apple will reject your app anyhow.